# textpos toggling noshowtext option

Tags: conditionals, textpos

Is there a way of toggling the `textpos` option `[noshowtext]`?

I would like some textboxes to show the frame but not the text. And others to show both frame and text, but can't seem to find a way of toggling this, the [package](http://www.tex.ac.uk/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/textpos/textpos.pdf) does not specify it.

Any ideas?

Comment: that is awesome! it works. Can you explain the `\TP@showtextfalse` and `\TP@showtexttrue` parts?  Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`textpos`](http://ctan.org/pkg/textpos) sets a boolean (or IF-condition) depending on whether you provide the `noshowtext` option or not. More specifically, from [`textpos.dtx`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/textpos/textpos.dtx), it defines (comments added):

```
\newif\ifTP@showtext% Create a condition \ifTP@showtext
\TP@showtexttrue% Set condition to TRUE
\DeclareOption{noshowtext}{\TP@showtextfalse}% Set condition to FALSE...
                                             % if you use \usepackage[noshowtext]{textpos}
```

If you add

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\NoShowText}{\TP@showtextfalse}% Set condition \ifTP@showtext to FALSE
\newcommand{\ShowText}{\TP@showtexttrue}% Set condition \ifTP@showtext to TRUE
\makeatother
```

to your document preamble, it provides a user-interface to setting the condition as either being TRUE or FALSE mid-document (rather than at package-load). So, they now act as a switch:

- Use `\NoShowText` to de-activate the showing of text; and
- Use `\ShowText` to activate the showing of text again.

This works because the condition is evaluated within the `textpos` constructions. If the constructions were created based on whether or not you load the package with/without the option, then it would be a different story; one may have to rewrite certain macros. But this doesn't seem to be the case here.

Comment: @Werner is correct -- this will work to switch the box text on and off. One should note, however, that the `@` in the macro name is telling you that this is an implementation detail of the class, which the package author (ie, me, in this case!) could change without warning and without scruple. That's unlikely to happen here, but it's wise to be conscious of that general potential downside to using packages' internal macros.

Answer (score 0):

Since textpos v1.8, you can do

```
\TPoptions{showtext=false}
```

(or `true`) to control showing and hiding the text.